# Adding resume function to stopwatch

Tags: java, swing

I have programmed a simple stopwatch with three functionalities. First, I have a start button to begin the stopwatch , a pause button to pause the stopwatch and finally a reset button to reset the entire stopwatch.

When I hit the pause button, the stopwatch pauses, say at 10.0 seconds. When I resume the stopwatch (pressing the Start button again), the stopwatch doesn't resume from 10.0 seconds onwards. It resumes from the amount of time I paused and the current time. For example, if I paused for 5 seconds and hit resume, the stopwatch goes from 15.0 seconds onwards.

I am aware there isn't a actual pause function in `Swing.Timer`. Would there be a way to tackle this so the stopwatch resumes normally?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class GuiStopwatch {





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch");

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();

          panel.setLayout(null);

          JButton startbtn = new JButton("START");  
          JButton pausebtn = new JButton("PAUSE");
          JButton reset = new JButton("RESET");
          JLabel time = new JLabel("Time shows here");
             panel.add(startbtn);
             panel.add(pausebtn);
            panel.add(reset);
            panel.add(time);
             startbtn.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 35);
             pausebtn.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 35);
             reset.setBounds(50, 250, 100, 35);
             time.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 35);
             time.setBackground(Color.black);
             time.setForeground(Color.red);
             frame.add(panel);



            Timer timer = new Timer(1,new ActionListener() {
                Instant start = Instant.now();
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                    time.setText( Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).getSeconds() +  ":" + Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).getNano() );


                }
            });



             startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {





                timer.start();




                }
            });



             pausebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    timer.stop();

                }
            });



             reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                time.setText("0:0");

                }
            });
```

Comment: So, the "basic" concept is - you need to keep track the total ruining time of the stop watch, that is the time from when it was first started to when it was paused. When resumed, you would then add the "new running" time to the previous tally

Comment: panel.setLayout(null); <— avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, the idea is, you want to keep track of the "total running" of the stop watch, this is, all the total duration it has been active.

There's a number of ways you might achieve this, one might be to simply keep a running total which is only updated when the stop watch is stopped or paused.  The "duration" of the stop watch is then a sum of the "current duration" of the "current" cycle and the "total previous" duration

Something like...

```
public class StopWatch {
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private Duration totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;

    public void start() {
        startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public void stop() {
        Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalDateTime.now());
        totalRunTime = totalRunTime.plus(runTime);
        startTime = null;
    }

    public void pause() {
        stop();
    }

    public void resume() {
        start();
    }

    public void reset() {
        stop();
        totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return startTime != null;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        Duration currentDuration = Duration.ZERO;
        currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(totalRunTime);
        if (isRunning()) {
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalDateTime.now());
            currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(runTime);
        }
        return currentDuration;
    }
}
```

Okay, so `start` and `stop` are essentially the same as `pause` and `resume`, but you get the point.

And, a runnable example...

Now, this example runs a Swing `Timer` constantly, but the `StopWatch` can `paused` and `resumed` at any time, the point is to demonstrate that the `StopWatch` is actually working correctly ;)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private JButton btn;

        private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            label = new JLabel("...");
            btn = new JButton("Start");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(label, gbc);
            add(btn, gbc);

            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText(Long.toString(stopWatch.getDuration().getSeconds()));
                }
            });
            timer.start();

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (stopWatch.isRunning()) {
                        stopWatch.pause();
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        stopWatch.resume();
                        btn.setText("Pause");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class StopWatch {
        private LocalDateTime startTime;
        private Duration totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;

        public void start() {
            startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        }

        public void stop() {
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalDateTime.now());
            totalRunTime = totalRunTime.plus(runTime);
            startTime = null;
        }

        public void pause() {
            stop();
        }

        public void resume() {
            start();
        }

        public void reset() {
            stop();
            totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return startTime != null;
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            Duration currentDuration = Duration.ZERO;
            currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(totalRunTime);
            if (isRunning()) {
                Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, LocalDateTime.now());
                currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(runTime);
            }
            return currentDuration;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So , `Instant.now()` is not ideal in my situation rather compared to using `LocalDateTime.now()` ?

Comment: @LordJesus To be honest, I just know how to deal with `LocalDateTime` :P

Comment: @LordJesus Did a quick check, replaced `LocalDateTime`  with `Instant` and seems to work just fine

Comment: I see. Your solution is fine but it's far more code written than mine. I guess to keep track of the "running" time, this is probably the best way to go?

Comment: I'm also comparing your solution to mine. I guess the difference is you added more logical code to keep track of the time and then upon clicking resume, you add it back to the previous tally. Am i correct?

Comment: I don’t know about “best”, but it’s a single point of reusable responsibility

Comment: *"then upon clicking resume, you add it back to the previous tally. Am i correct?"* - in basic way.  The idea is to calculate the "running" time (between start and stop), this gets added to a "tally", so we can filter out the time between pause and resume.  All "duration" calculates for the stop watch itself, then include this "tally" onto of any additional "running time" that might be occurring. Conceptually it's not complicated (you could write it out on a sheet of paper), but it just wraps up the functionality into a single, reusable source - so it's independent of the how you might use it

Comment: I see. I was hoping there is a single function like Timer.Pause() that saves you the trouble to write and store these tallies, but of course swing doesn't have this function to do that. Is there other library API that has this type of function, say JavaFX ? Althought I am not familiar with JavaFx.

Comment: Never knew programming a small and simple program takes some time and logic along with long line of code. I can only imagine a much complex program, would require so much more sources.

Comment: *"Is there other library API that has this type of function"* - I doubt it. There might be a third party library which does, but I don't know of any and have just used the above technique. I've worked in a number of a languages and none of them have a concept of a "stop watch" as you've described it. *"I can only imagine a much complex program, would require so much more sources"* - Small units of work, built up to make larger ones - this is one reason why there are so many third party libraries. A good API is one which provides you flexibility to adapt it to your needs