# Use of a thread messes up my pausing system

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, milliseconds

There is something wrong with my code. The timer overall seems to be working fine and the pause button does its job.

The problem is when you pause the clock at a specific time and then you unpause it.

If we (let's say) pause it at 8 seconds and we unpause it after a minute, it doesn't keep going like 9-10-11, etc. It goes 74-75-76... (I've broken it into minutes and seconds).

Is it a  thread that causes the problem? (Also, I've overused freeze_sec and freeze_min time code snippets just to see if it would be fixed but it wasn't.)

Here is the code:

```
Thread t1 = null;

ss = new ServerSocket(6800);
while(true) {
    s = ss.accept();
    isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    message = br.readLine();

    if (message.equals("START")) {
        t1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        t1.start();

        ...

    } else if (message.equals("PAUSE")) {
        if(check) {
            try {
                check = false;
                Thread1.PAUSE(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception e");
        }
    } else {
        check = true;
        Thread1.PAUSE(false);
    }
}
```

And Thread1 class looks like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Thread1 extends MyServerFrame implements Runnable{

    private static int current_min_time = 0;
    private static int current_sec_time = 0;
    private static int freeze_min_time = 0;
    private static int freeze_sec_time = 0;
    private static boolean pause = false;
    private static int minutes = 0;
    private int total_time_sec = 0;
    private static boolean freeze_signal = false;
    private static int k = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long elapsedTime = 0L;

        boolean bool = true;
        int num = 0;

        while (bool) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (minutes == 0) {
                System.out.println("How many minutes for this half-time?");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                num = in.nextInt();
                minutes = num;
            }

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (total_time_sec < minutes * 60 || freeze_signal == false) {

                if (freeze_signal && k == 0) {
                    freeze_sec_time = current_sec_time;
                    freeze_min_time = current_min_time;
                    k++;
                }

                if (!pause) {
                    //perform db poll/check
                    if (elapsedTime / 1000 != current_sec_time) {
                        try {
                            clearTheFile("Half_Time.txt");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Exception");
                        }
                        if (!freeze_signal && k > 0) {
                            current_sec_time = freeze_sec_time;
                            current_min_time = freeze_min_time;
                            k = 0;
                        }
                        current_sec_time++;
                        total_time_sec = current_sec_time + current_min_time / 60;
                        print_in_txt();
                    }
                    elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

                    if (current_sec_time == 60) {
                        if (!freeze_signal && k > 0) {
                            current_sec_time = freeze_sec_time;
                            current_min_time = freeze_min_time;
                            try {
                                clearTheFile("Half_Time.txt");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Exception");
                            }
                            print_in_txt();
                            k = 0;
                        }
                        current_sec_time = 0;
                        current_min_time++;
                        total_time_sec = current_sec_time + current_min_time / 60;
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
                        try {
                            clearTheFile("Half_Time.txt");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Exception");
                        }
                        print_in_txt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }        

    public static void clearTheFile(String txt_name) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileWriter fwOb = new FileWriter(txt_name, false);
            PrintWriter pwOb = new PrintWriter(fwOb, false);
            pwOb.flush();
            pwOb.close();
            fwOb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public static void print_in_txt() {
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter("Half_Time.txt");
            out.println(String.format("%02d", current_min_time) + ":" + String.format("%02d", current_sec_time));
            out.print("");
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File doesn't exist");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void PAUSE(boolean p) {
        if (p) {
            pause = true;
            freeze_signal = true;
        } else {
            current_sec_time = freeze_sec_time;
            current_min_time = freeze_min_time;
            try {
                clearTheFile("Half_Time.txt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
            print_in_txt();
            pause = false;
            freeze_signal = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your codes a little bit of a mess, but, the basic concept you need to get is: You have a "total run time", this is all the time that your clocks has been running (excluding pauses).  You then have a "cycle time", which is the amount of time which the clock as been allowed to run before been paused.  Each time the thread is paused, you would take the "cycle time" add it to the "total run time" and reset the "cycle time".

Comment: When the clock is unpaused, you would grab the current time and begin cycling again, where the "cycle time" becomes the amount of time the block has been running since been unpaused

Comment: I would also avoid using `Date` and instead use `java.time.Instant` and `java.time`'s duration support

Comment: I tried to squeeze a lot of hours today on this project and it's the last thing that remains bugged. That's why it mostly is a mess. So, if I get it correctly, what I'm always seeing is the 'total run time', but I simply want to remove the pauses' duration. Is that the 'cycle time' + 'total time' and the reset of 'cycle time'? How do I reset the 'cycle time'?

Comment: Ok, I've been bagging my head against this for a short period of time, but then I realised, you don't actually need the `Thread` to achieve the timing.  You just need to be able to determine the "current" time when inspected.  To this end, you could use a simple `StopWatch` class, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978554/pause-and-resume-for-swing-timer-does-not-work-properly/52979420#52979420)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the post a bit to make an understanding of your issue easier. It includes a lot of code and it is really important to keep it well-formatted. People who read the question might want to skip it because they see they need to read a lot of code, so why not to help them a bit by making the code a little more readable. Also minor text formatting - to make it more clear where is "what you have done" description and where is the question itself.

Happy Hacking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending some time bagging my head against the idea, I suddenly realised that you don't actually need the thread at all.

What you need is a way to calculate the duration between two points in time, which doesn't need a thread to update the state, it's done automatically.

The thread is just doing "other stuff"

So, based on that, I took a `StopWatch` class from one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978554/pause-and-resume-for-swing-timer-does-not-work-properly/52979420#52979420)...

```
public class StopWatch {

    private Instant startTime;
    private Duration totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;

    public StopWatch start() {
        startTime = Instant.now();
        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch stop() {
        Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
        totalRunTime = totalRunTime.plus(runTime);
        startTime = null;
        return this;
    }

    public StopWatch pause() {
        return stop();
    }

    public StopWatch resume() {
        return start();
    }

    public StopWatch reset() {
        stop();
        totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return startTime != null;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        Duration currentDuration = Duration.ZERO;
        currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(totalRunTime);
        if (isRunning()) {
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
            currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(runTime);
        }
        return currentDuration;
    }
}
```

And applied so it could be used within a `Thread`, which would simply print the running time.

Around this, I added the ability to pause, resume and stop the thread so as to demonstrate the basic idea...

```
public class StopWatchRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final Lock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition pauseCondtion = pauseLock.newCondition();
    private final AtomicBoolean isPaused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    private final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopWatch.start();
        while (isRunning.get()) {
            while (isPaused.get()) {
                pauseLock.lock();
                stopWatch.pause();
                try {
                    pauseCondtion.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                } finally {
                    pauseLock.unlock();
                    stopWatch.resume();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            Duration duration = stopWatch.getDuration();
            String formatted = String.format("%dhrs %02dmins, %02dseconds", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
            System.out.println(formatted);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        pauseLock.lock();
        try {
            isPaused.set(false);
            isRunning.set(false);
        } finally {
            pauseCondtion.signalAll();
            pauseLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        pauseLock.lock();
        try {
            isPaused.set(true);
        } finally {
            pauseLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        pauseLock.lock();
        try {
            isPaused.set(false);
        } finally {
            pauseCondtion.signalAll();
            pauseLock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

## Runnable example...

This basically takes the code from above and dumps it into a simple runnable example which demonstrates the pause/resume functionality

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class StopWatchExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new StopWatchExample();
    }

    public StopWatchExample() throws InterruptedException {
        StopWatchRunnable stopWatch = new StopWatchRunnable();
        Thread thread = new Thread(stopWatch);
        thread.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Pause...");
        stopWatch.pause();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Resume...");
        stopWatch.resume();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Stop...");
        stopWatch.stop();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println("All done...");
    }

    public class StopWatch {

        private Instant startTime;
        private Duration totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;

        public StopWatch start() {
            startTime = Instant.now();
            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch stop() {
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
            totalRunTime = totalRunTime.plus(runTime);
            startTime = null;
            return this;
        }

        public StopWatch pause() {
            return stop();
        }

        public StopWatch resume() {
            return start();
        }

        public StopWatch reset() {
            stop();
            totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;
            return this;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return startTime != null;
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            Duration currentDuration = Duration.ZERO;
            currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(totalRunTime);
            if (isRunning()) {
                Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
                currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(runTime);
            }
            return currentDuration;
        }
    }

    public class StopWatchRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final Lock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
        private final Condition pauseCondtion = pauseLock.newCondition();
        private final AtomicBoolean isPaused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        private final AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        private final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopWatch.start();
            while (isRunning.get()) {
                while (isPaused.get()) {
                    pauseLock.lock();
                    stopWatch.pause();
                    try {
                        pauseCondtion.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    } finally {
                        pauseLock.unlock();
                        stopWatch.resume();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                Duration duration = stopWatch.getDuration();
                String formatted = String.format("%dhrs %02dmins, %02dseconds", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
                System.out.println(formatted);
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            pauseLock.lock();
            try {
                isPaused.set(false);
                isRunning.set(false);
            } finally {
                pauseCondtion.signalAll();
                pauseLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            pauseLock.lock();
            try {
                isPaused.set(true);
            } finally {
                pauseLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        public void resume() {
            pauseLock.lock();
            try {
                isPaused.set(false);
            } finally {
                pauseCondtion.signalAll();
                pauseLock.unlock();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Holy moly, thank you so much for the effort. I really appreciate so many quick, detailed and helpful responses and the code for it as well. Can't thank you enough