# Hello, I'm making a digital clock that will change to a stopwatch when the spacebar is pressed. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java

The code shows that the "setTimer" method is not applicable for the boolean type and the methods "isRunning" and "isStopwatchKeyPressed" are undefined.

ClockProject Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
 
 
public class ClockProject extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
 
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JLabel dayLabel;
    JLabel dateLabel;
    String time;
    String day;
    String date;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
 
    //Sets format and appearance of the clock
    public ClockProject() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Ryan's Digital Clock");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(350, 220);
        setResizable(false);
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
 
        timeLabel = new JLabel();
        timeLabel.setFont(new Font("SANS_SERIF", Font.PLAIN, 59));
        timeLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        timeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        timeLabel.setOpaque(true);
 
        dayLabel = new JLabel();
        dayLabel.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 34));
        dateLabel = new JLabel();
        dateLabel.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 30));
        add(timeLabel);
        add(dayLabel);
        add(dateLabel);
        setVisible(true);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        readFromFile("data.txt");
        for (String data : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        setTimer();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            setTimer(false); //stop the clock
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.setVisible(true); //open the stopwatch
            removeKeyListener(this); //remove the key listener from the frame
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
 
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
 
    // Count control using a while loop in setTimer() method
    public void setTimer() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            time = timeFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            timeLabel.setText(time);
            day = dayFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            dayLabel.setText(day);
            date = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            dateLabel.setText(date);
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                timeLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                timeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
 
    // Polymorphism using method overloading for readFromFile() method.
    public void readFromFile(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                arrayList.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    public void writeToFile(String filename) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
            for (String data : arrayList) {
                writer.write(data + "\n");
            }
 
            writer.close();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Help.about();
    boolean isStopwatchActive = false;
    while (true) {
        if (isStopwatchActive) {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); 
            stopwatch.setVisible(true);
            while (true) {
                stopwatch.setTimer();
                if (!stopwatch.isRunning()) {
                    isStopwatchActive = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ClockProject clock = new ClockProject();
            clock.writeToFile("data.txt");
            while (true) {
                clock.setTimer();
                if (clock.isStopwatchKeyPressed()) {
                    isStopwatchActive = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Stopwatch class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Stopwatch extends ClockProject implements KeyListener {
    private long startTime;
    private boolean running;
    private long elapsedTime;

    // constructor and other methods

    @Override
    public void setTimer() {
        if (!running) {
            // add a KeyListener to the Frame
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            running = true;
        }
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Long hours = elapsedTime / 3600000;
        long minutes = (elapsedTime / 60000) % 60;
        long seconds = (elapsedTime / 1000) % 60;
        timeLabel.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(18);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Implement the KeyListener methods to stop the stopwatch
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            running = false;
            removeKeyListener(this);
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // not used
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // not used
    }
}
```

I tried finding the reason why the setTimer method could not be used as a boolean type but could not figure it out.

Comment: The `while(true)` loop in the `main` method is a really, really, really bad idea. `setTimer` does not take any parameters, even if you could call it, you'd be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread and the UI would be unable to be updated.  `KeyListener` is generally a bad way to monitor keyboard input, instead make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Comment: I would avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`; you're not extending any of the functionality of the class and you're locking yourself into a single use case.  For example, it might be easier to use a `CardLayout` to switch between the "clock" and the "stop watch", if they were based on a `JPanel`

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I would decouple the "clock" and "stop watch" models - these should be capable of reporting information back to the UI, so you could, technically, use the same UI for both - for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408678/adding-resume-function-to-stopwatch/50409049#50409049); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978554/pause-and-resume-for-swing-timer-does-not-work-properly/52979420#52979420)

Comment: *"the methods `isRunning` and `isStopwatchKeyPressed` are undefined."*  You showed us code in which each of these methods is called. But, you have no code that has code for these methods.  So, they are undefined.  You have code for method `void setTimer ()` in `class ClockProject` and you overrode it in `class Stopwatch`. As defined, those methods don't take any argument. So, a call to one can't have an argument.

Answer (score 4):

This...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Help.about();
    boolean isStopwatchActive = false;
    while (true) {
        if (isStopwatchActive) {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); 
            stopwatch.setVisible(true);
            while (true) {
                stopwatch.setTimer();
                if (!stopwatch.isRunning()) {
                    isStopwatchActive = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ClockProject clock = new ClockProject();
            clock.writeToFile("data.txt");
            while (true) {
                clock.setTimer();
                if (clock.isStopwatchKeyPressed()) {
                    isStopwatchActive = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is a bad idea.  This is not how a UI should work.  Apart from the fact that fact that you're trying to read state from another thread context, which could result in dirty reads, your `while-loop` is "free wheeling" which will consume CPU time and have a degrading performance on your whole system.

There's also no escape out of the inner loops, so, now you're completely stuck.

Swing, like most UIs, is event driven, that is, something happens and you respond to it.  What you've presented here instead is more procedural in nature.

`setTimer` does not take any parameters, even if you could call it, you'd be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread and the UI would be unable to be updated.

`KeyListener` is generally a bad way to monitor keyboard input, instead make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

I would avoid extending from top level containers like `JFrame`; you're not extending any of the functionality of the class and you're locking yourself into a single use case. For example, it might be easier to use a `CardLayout` to switch between the "clock" and the "stop watch" views, if they were based on a `JPanel`. –

I would recommend taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

## A "simple" implementation...

Let's take a step back for a second and try and take in the "big picture".  You want to display some time information, either from a "wall clock" or "stop watch".

I would decouple the concepts and the UI, so that the "presentation" of the time was seperated from the "calculation" of the time, this then provides us with the concept of a "model" (or data) and the "view".  The presentation of the data should be decided by the view, which is why, in the following example, I've excluded providing any kind of formatting at the model level.

Both these could be used to display `hour`, `minute` and `second` information, so, let's start there...

```
public interface Time {
    public int getHours();
    public int getMinutes();
    public int getSeconds();
}
```

Now, you need some kind of "container" which managers this information, for this I've used a `Clock`...

```
public interface Clock {
    public Time getTime();
}
```

There's a pretty basic, but lay down the core contracts.

To make life a little more easier, I created a "default" implementation of `Time`

```
public class DefaultTime implements Time {        
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    public DefaultTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public DefaultTime(LocalTime time) {
        this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
    }

    public DefaultTime(Duration duration) {
        this(duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }
}
```

With these in hand, we can create a `WallClock` and `StopWatch` implementation...

```
public class WallClock implements Clock {
    @Override
    public Time getTime() {
        return new DefaultTime(LocalTime.now());
    }
}

public class StopWatch implements Clock {
    
    private Instant startTime;
    private Instant stopTime;
    
    public void start() {
        startTime = Instant.now();
        stopTime = null;
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        if (startTime == null) {
             return;
        }
        stopTime = Instant.now();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Time getTime() {
        if (startTime == null) {
            return new DefaultTime(0, 0, 0);
        }
        Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, stopTime == null ? Instant.now() : stopTime);
        return new DefaultTime(duration);
    }
}
```

What's important here is, the `StopWatch` has some additional functionality, it can be started and stopped, this demonstrates how functionality can be expended and separated based on your needs.

Now, finally, we need some way to display it...

```
public class ClockPane extends JPanel {
    enum State {
        WALL_CLOCK, STOP_WATCH;
    }
    
    private State state = State.WALL_CLOCK;
    private Clock clock = new WallClock();
    
    private Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateTime();
        }
    });

    private JLabel timeDisplay;
    
    public ClockPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
        
        timeDisplay = new JLabel();
        timeDisplay.setFont(timeDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(48f));
        
        add(timeDisplay);
        updateTime();
        
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "Space.pressed");
        actionMap.put("Space.pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switch (getState()) {
                    case WALL_CLOCK:
                        setState(State.STOP_WATCH);
                        break;
                        
                    case STOP_WATCH:
                        setState(State.WALL_CLOCK);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeNotify() {
        super.removeNotify();
        timer.stop();
    }
    
    protected void updateTime() {
        Time time = getClock().getTime();
        timeDisplay.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds()));
    }

    public Clock getClock() {
        return clock;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
        switch (state) {
            case WALL_CLOCK:
                clock = new WallClock();
                break;
                
            case STOP_WATCH:
                StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
                stopWatch.start();
                clock = stopWatch;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty basic. We allow the presentation of two "states", a wall clock or stop watch.  In doing so, we simply switch the underlying `Clock` implementation to be used to generate the `Time` value.

The UI then makes use of a simple Swing `Timer` to update the `Time` value on the UI at a regular interval.

It also has a key binding, binding the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, so that when pressed, we simple switch state between the `WALL_CLOCK` and `STOP_WATCH`

### Runnable example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ClockPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClockPane extends JPanel {
        enum State {
            WALL_CLOCK, STOP_WATCH;
        }

        private State state = State.WALL_CLOCK;
        private Clock clock = new WallClock();

        private Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateTime();
            }
        });

        private JLabel timeDisplay;

        public ClockPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            timeDisplay = new JLabel();
            timeDisplay.setFont(timeDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(48f));

            add(timeDisplay);
            updateTime();

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "Space.pressed");
            actionMap.put("Space.pressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switch (getState()) {
                        case WALL_CLOCK:
                            setState(State.STOP_WATCH);
                            break;

                        case STOP_WATCH:
                            setState(State.WALL_CLOCK);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        protected void updateTime() {
            Time time = getClock().getTime();
            timeDisplay.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds()));
        }

        public Clock getClock() {
            return clock;
        }

        public State getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(State state) {
            this.state = state;
            switch (state) {
                case WALL_CLOCK:
                    clock = new WallClock();
                    break;

                case STOP_WATCH:
                    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
                    stopWatch.start();
                    clock = stopWatch;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface Time {
        public int getHours();
        public int getMinutes();
        public int getSeconds();
    }

    public interface Clock {
        public Time getTime();
    }

    public class DefaultTime implements Time {        
        private int hours;
        private int minutes;
        private int seconds;

        public DefaultTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }

        public DefaultTime(LocalTime time) {
            this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
        }

        public DefaultTime(Duration duration) {
            this(duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        }

        @Override
        public int getHours() {
            return hours;
        }

        @Override
        public int getMinutes() {
            return minutes;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSeconds() {
            return seconds;
        }
    }

    public class WallClock implements Clock {
        @Override
        public Time getTime() {
            return new DefaultTime(LocalTime.now());
        }
    }

    public class StopWatch implements Clock {

        private Instant startTime;
        private Instant stopTime;

        public void start() {
            startTime = Instant.now();
            stopTime = null;
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                 return;
            }
            stopTime = Instant.now();
        }

        @Override
        public Time getTime() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                return new DefaultTime(0, 0, 0);
            }
            Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, stopTime == null ? Instant.now() : stopTime);
            return new DefaultTime(duration);
        }
    }
}
```

## But what if we want something more complicated?

What if we want to format the wall clock time differently?  What if we want to add in controls for the stop watch?

Well, then, you'd create specialised implementations of the view to support it and then, possibly, use a `CardLayout` to switch between them.

First, we create a  wall clock view.  This will display the time in `hour:minute:second daypart` format (ie 2:30:00 pm)

Next, the stop watch view. The format remains unchanged, but will  add a "start/stop" button, so you can control the stop watch.

We also update the `StopWatch` to add a `isRunning` method, so we can tell when it's "running" or not, so we can start/stop it appropriatly.

Then we update the `ClockPane` so we can switch between the views. This is making use of a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which makes it really simple to switch between different views...

### Runnable example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new ClockPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ClockPane extends JPanel {
        enum State {
            WALL_CLOCK, STOP_WATCH;
        }

        private State state = State.WALL_CLOCK;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public ClockPane() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();

            setLayout(cardLayout);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            add(new WallClockPane(), "WALL_CLOCK");
            add(new StopWatchPane(), "STOP_WATCH");

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "Space.pressed");
            actionMap.put("Space.pressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switch (getState()) {
                        case WALL_CLOCK:
                            setState(State.STOP_WATCH);
                            break;

                        case STOP_WATCH:
                            setState(State.WALL_CLOCK);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public State getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(State state) {
            this.state = state;
            switch (state) {
                case WALL_CLOCK:
                    cardLayout.show(this, "WALL_CLOCK");
                    break;

                case STOP_WATCH:
                    cardLayout.show(this, "STOP_WATCH");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class WallClockPane extends JPanel {
        private Clock clock = new WallClock();

        private Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateTime();
            }
        });

        private JLabel timeDisplay;
        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");

        public WallClockPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            timeDisplay = new JLabel();
            timeDisplay.setFont(timeDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(48f));

            add(timeDisplay);
            updateTime();
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        protected void updateTime() {
            Time time = getClock().getTime();
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds());
            timeDisplay.setText(localTime.format(formatter));
        }

        public Clock getClock() {
            return clock;
        }
    }

    public class StopWatchPane extends JPanel {
        private StopWatch clock = new StopWatch();

        private Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateTime();
            }
        });

        private JLabel timeDisplay;

        private JButton toggleStateButton;

        public StopWatchPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));

            timeDisplay = new JLabel();
            timeDisplay.setFont(timeDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(48f));

            toggleStateButton = new JButton("Start");
            toggleStateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (clock.isRunning()) {
                        toggleStateButton.setText("Start");
                        clock.stop();
                    } else {
                        toggleStateButton.setText("Stop");
                        clock.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(timeDisplay, gbc);
            add(toggleStateButton, gbc);
            updateTime();
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        protected void updateTime() {
            Time time = getClock().getTime();
            timeDisplay.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds()));
        }

        public Clock getClock() {
            return clock;
        }
    }

    public interface Time {
        public int getHours();

        public int getMinutes();

        public int getSeconds();
    }

    public interface Clock {
        public Time getTime();
    }

    public class DefaultTime implements Time {
        private int hours;
        private int minutes;
        private int seconds;

        public DefaultTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }

        public DefaultTime(LocalTime time) {
            this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
        }

        public DefaultTime(Duration duration) {
            this(duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        }

        @Override
        public int getHours() {
            return hours;
        }

        @Override
        public int getMinutes() {
            return minutes;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSeconds() {
            return seconds;
        }
    }

    public class WallClock implements Clock {
        @Override
        public Time getTime() {
            return new DefaultTime(LocalTime.now());
        }
    }

    public class StopWatch implements Clock {

        private Instant startTime;
        private Instant stopTime;

        private boolean isRunning = false;

        public void start() {
            startTime = Instant.now();
            stopTime = null;
            isRunning = true;
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                return;
            }
            stopTime = Instant.now();
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return isRunning;
        }

        @Override
        public Time getTime() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                return new DefaultTime(0, 0, 0);
            }
            Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, stopTime == null ? Instant.now() : stopTime);
            return new DefaultTime(duration);
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting thing about this is...

1. The stop watch will continue running if you switch back to the wall clock view (you can change this behaviour, but I thought it was an interesting side effect)
2. The button will consume the <kbd>Space</kbd> event, so you might want to consider the key binding or provide another navigation workflow, maybe using a `JTabbedPane` instead

## Dependency Injection

You could pass the `Clock` and a "formatter" into a common view component, instead of specialising the views.

These are just a view ideas.