# Java Countdown Timer reset issue

Tags: java, netbeans, countdown

I have coded a countdown timer in java. It counts down from whatever number a user selects in a combo box, there are 3 of them (hour, minute, second). This part is working perfectly fine.

The issue comes when I press my "Reset" button. It clears the labels I use to display the time left, and makes them display "00". But when I press start again, it recalls where it last was in terms of seconds left and starts there.

Please help!!

Here is my code for the timer:

```
private void JButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        onoff = true; 


        if(hours == 1 && min == 0 && sec ==0){

            repaint();
            hours--;
            lblHours.setText("00");
            min=59;
            sec=60;

        }

         if(sec == 0 && min <= 59 && min>0){   

             sec=60;
             min--;
             lblHours.setText("00");

         }

         if(sec == 0 && hours == 0 && min<=0){

             repaint();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "You have run out of time and did not manage to escape!", "Time is up!!", 0 );
             hours = 0; min = 0; sec = 0;
             timer.stop();
         }

         else{

             sec--;
             repaint();

             if (sec<10){

             lblSeconds.setText("0"+sec);
             repaint();
             flag = false;

             }
             if (hours==0){

                 repaint();
                 lblHours.setText("00");

             if (min<10)

                 repaint();
                 lblMinutes.setText("0"+min);

                 if (sec<10)

                     lblSeconds.setText("0"+sec);

                 else

                     lblSeconds.setText(""+sec);


             }
             if(flag){
             lblHours.setText(""+hours);
             lblMinutes.setText(""+min);
             lblSeconds.setText(""+sec);
             repaint();

             }


         }
    }

});

    timer.start();


}
```

And my code for the reset button is here:

```
    onoff =false;


    timer.stop();
    repaint();

    lblHours.setText("00");
    lblMinutes.setText("00");
    lblSeconds.setText("00");
    repaint();
```

I know I go a bit crazy with the repaint(); but I have no idea how often I am meant to use it lol.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't reset `hours`, `min`, `second`

Comment: Where do you reset `hours`, `min` and `sec`?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this is some what of a naive approach.  Swing `Timer` (and even `Thread.sleep`) only guarantee "at least" duration.  Okay, so it's not a super high-resolution timer, but you still need to understand that this can cause a "drift" to occur, especially over a large period.  A "better" solution would be to calculate the time passed since the timer was started.  Lucky for us, Java now includes a lot of support for this - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408678/adding-resume-function-to-stopwatch/50409049#50409049)

Answer (score 1):

No where in you available, out-of-context, code do you reset the variables `hours`, `min`, `second`.

This could have been solved by simply putting in some print statements around your data and probably some simple [desk check](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=desk+check&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) of your states.

Having said that, this is some what of a naive approach.

Swing `Timer` (and even `Thread.sleep`) only guarantee "at least" duration.

Okay, so you're not developing a super high-resolution timer, but you still need to understand that this can cause a "drift" to occur, especially over a large period.

A "better" solution would be to calculate the time passed since the timer was started.  Lucky for us, Java now includes a lot of support for this in the form of its newer date/time API.

The following example makes uses of a simple "stop watch" concept, which is simply the amount of time which has passed since it was started.  It itself doesn't actual tick, making it very efficient.

But how is a forward moving clock going to help you?  A lot actually.  You can calculate the time remaining but subtracting the desired run time from the current amount of time passed (since it was started) and you have a count down.  Simple.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

  public class StopWatch {

    private Instant startTime;
    private Duration totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;

    public void start() {
      startTime = Instant.now();
    }

    public void stop() {
      Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
      totalRunTime = totalRunTime.plus(runTime);
      startTime = null;
    }

    public void pause() {
      stop();
    }

    public void resume() {
      start();
    }

    public void reset() {
      stop();
      totalRunTime = Duration.ZERO;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
      return startTime != null;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
      Duration currentDuration = Duration.ZERO;
      currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(totalRunTime);
      if (isRunning()) {
        Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
        currentDuration = currentDuration.plus(runTime);
      }
      return currentDuration;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton btn;

    private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    private Timer timer;

    public TestPane() {
      label = new JLabel("...");
      btn = new JButton("Start");

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

      add(label, gbc);
      add(btn, gbc);

      timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Duration runningTime = Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
          Duration remainingTime = runningTime.minus(stopWatch.getDuration());
          System.out.println("RemainingTime = " + remainingTime);
          if (remainingTime.isZero() || remainingTime.isNegative()) {
            timer.stop();
            label.setText("0hrs 0mins 0secs");
          } else {
            long hours = remainingTime.toHours();
            long mins = remainingTime.toMinutesPart();
            long secs = remainingTime.toSecondsPart();
            label.setText(String.format("%dhrs %02dmins %02dsecs", hours, mins, secs));
          }
        }
      });
      timer.start();

      btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (stopWatch.isRunning()) {
            stopWatch.pause();
            btn.setText("Start");
          } else {
            stopWatch.resume();
            btn.setText("Pause");
          }
        }
      });

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

  }

}
```