# How to call a Swing Timer from Inside a JButton

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to start a Timer after a button is pressed.

The following code without a button works

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
    timer.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However when I put it inside a button

```
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

It does not print anything when the button is pressed.

I thought this occurred because the main thread ends, so I tried adding a `while (true)` at the end, but it did not change anything.

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of `Thread.sleep(10000);`

Comment: That worked - but how would I stop it after a certain time now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `Thread.sleep(10000);`, it's cause the Event Dispatching Thread to sleep for 10 seconds, which is stopping it from process the the Event Queue, which where the `Timer` will post it's "action" events to run

Take a look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            System.out.println("...");
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

    }


}
```

> but how would I stop it after a certain time now?

That's a more difficult answer.  First, you would need to make it an instance field so you can reference it.

Second, you could either use a second `Timer`, set to the specified timeout (and set not to repeat) and when it fires, stop the first `Timer` or, use something like `Instant` to calculate the difference between when the timer was started and now, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253671/java-countdown-timer-reset-issue/53253836#53253836) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978554/pause-and-resume-for-swing-timer-does-not-work-properly/52979420#52979420) (at the lest the second half)