# Adding pause and resume methods to stopwatch class

Tags: java

How do I add pause and resume methods to this class?
When you pause and it is already paused then nothing should happen.
Also if you resume when it is not paused nothing should happen.

```
public class Stopwatch {
  private final long start;

  public Stopwatch() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();}

  public double elapsedTime() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (now - start) / 1000.0;}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    double total = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) 
      total += Math.random();

    double time = watch.elapsedTime();

    StdOut.println(time);

  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding resume function to stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408678/adding-resume-function-to-stopwatch)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hold a variable `accumulatedTime` and when the `pause()` method is called you append the accumulated time to it

```
accumulatedTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - start / 1000.0;
```

When `resume()` is called you could reset start

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then `elapsedTime()` would add the two:

```
public double elapsedTime() {
   long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
   return ((now - start) / 1000.0) + accumulatedTime;
}
```

You'd also need to track the paused state - a `isPaused` `boolean` instance variable perhaps? And then your `pause()/resume()` can response if appropriate 
e.g. in `pause()` method:

```
if (isPaused) {
   return;   //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paused time is stored in the additionaltime variable, this will be used to remove paused time when called elapsedTime. PauseStart variable stores when the pause is called(After resume call the additionaltime is calculated)

```
private long additionalTime;

private long pauseStart;

public void pause() {
    if (pauseStart == 0) {
        pauseStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

public void resume() {
    if (pauseStart != 0) {

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseStart;

        additionalTime += stopTime;

        pauseStart = 0;
    }
}

public double elapsedTime() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (pauseStart != 0) {

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseStart;

        additionalTime += stopTime;

        pauseStart = 0;
    }

    return ((now - start) - additionalTime) / 1000.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! When I call watch.pause() and then display watch.elapsedTime() it works. But when I display watch.elapsedTime() later without pausing again the time has changed... instead of showing the same value again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stopwatch is currently tied to the System time (System.currentTimeMillis()), so to pause the application you would need to subtract the time that you paused from your elapsed time somehow
What you could do though is to have save the time that you pause the clock, and what time it is resumed:

```
pause() {
  if(!alreadyPaused)
    timePaused = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
resume() {
  timeResumed = System.currentTimeMillis();
  totalTimePaused = previousPausedTimes + (timeResumed-timePaused);
}
```

and then in your elapsedTime():

```
  public double elapsedTime() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (now - start - totalTimePaused) / 1000.0;
  }
```